Palabra para el acto de explicar fenómenos naturales usando leyendas o mitos
Sé que alguna vez leí en el diccionario de la RAE la definición de una palabra que denotaba el acto (comúnmente primitivo) de explicar fenómenos naturales o de otro tipo mediante mitos, leyendas, imaginación etc.
He tratado de recordar la palabra y de buscarla pero no lo he logrado y me está carcomiendo la duda.
¿Alguien conoce esa palabra?

¿Convertir en mito cualquier hecho natural? Esa es una de las definiciones de mitificar. Aunque a los mejor el término que buscas es fabular.

Mito etiológico natural
Los mitos etiológicos son aquellos mitos que narran y explican el origen de fenómenos naturales, seres, objetos, rituales o costumbres.

Existen tres subtipos de mitos etiológicos: naturales, etimológicos y religiosos.Un mito etiológico natural explica un aspecto de la naturaleza. Por ejemplo, podrías explicar relámpagos y truenos diciendo que Zeus está enojado.Un mito etiológico etimológico explica el origen de una palabra. (La etimología es el estudio de los orígenes de las palabras.) Por ejemplo, podrías explicar el nombre de la diosa, Afrodita, diciendo que nació en espuma de mar, ya que aphros es la palabra griega para espuma de mar.Un mito etiológico religioso explica el origen de un ritual religioso. Por ejemplo, podrías explicar el ritual religioso griego de los Misterios Eleusinos diciendo que se originaron cuando la diosa griega, Demeter, bajó a la ciudad de Eleusis y enseñó a la gente a adorarla.

Fuente espanol.libretexts.org
